# MonoDevelop - Highlighting type names

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Is there a way to configure MonoDevelop to highlight type-names like VS does?

I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4 on Fedora-17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MonoDevelop [semantic highlighting is back on 3.0](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_3.0#Semantic_Highlighting)
I've got MD working on Ubuntu- though I have it running by pulling source from github and (after doing all the necessary build steps) calling make run- in case you would like to give it a go; I can highly recommend moving to 3.0.. (if possible), it's got some other refactoring capabilities that make it worth it!

Answer (score 2):

In order to get semantic highlighting, you'll need to upgrade to MonoDevelop 3.0.x